# In Wordpress, can you get the post ID from a comment ID

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, given the ID of a comment is it possible to get the ID of the post that the comment is attached to?

For example, comment with ID 1642 is attached to post with ID 172

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `get_comment()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment  Make sure to read the parameters for the function in the above link.  You must pass a variable containing an integer with this function.

```
<?php
    $my_id = 7;
    $comment_id_7 = get_comment( $my_id ); 
    $comment_post_id = $comment_id_7->comment_post_ID ;
?>
```